# can't set authorization on header request?

Tags: javascript, fetch

i already have this code on my express server:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
  next();
});
app.use('/graphql', graphqlExpress(async(req) => {
  let {user} = await getUser(req.headers.authorization);
  return ({
    schema,
    pretty: true,
    graphiql: true,
    context: {
      user
    }
  })
}))
```

I thought it was cors problem so I followed from this tutorial in enable-cors for express: https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

This code is how i process fetching:

```
let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
const fetchQuery = (operation, variables) => {
  return fetch('/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': token,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({query: operation.text, variables})
  }).then(response => {
    // A better error message for request timeouts
    if (response.status === 504) {
      return Promise.reject({
        error: {
          message: 'Request timed out'
        }
      })
    }
    return response.json()
  }).then(responseJson => {
    // https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1816
    // https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1913
    if (responseJson.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(responseJson.errors[0])
    }
    return Promise.resolve(responseJson)
  })
}
```

But, even though there's already a token after a user logs in, the authorization sent to server is always null?

Comment: where is the codes to add token into the localStorage?

Comment: it happens after a user logs in, so on first render of the app, authorization is expected to be null, but after a user logs in, on the localstorage i can see the token there, but on request, authorization is null

Comment: what about call `fetch` with `'Authorization': 'test'` ? the authorization is still null?

Comment: i have done that, if there is no token on mount, authorization cannot ever be set :(, it's updating on localstorage as i said, but always sent is null

Comment: Maybe `localStorage.getItem("token")` is never executing. Try moving that line inside `fetchQuery`

Comment: @SrThompson i'm weirded out it worked like a magic

Comment: Javascript is full of surprises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage.getItem("token")` is not executing, probably due to `getItem` being an I/O operation, and how exporting works. Move it inside `fetchQuery`

```
const fetchQuery = (operation, variables) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  return fetch('/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': token,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({query: operation.text, variables})
  }).then(response => {
    // A better error message for request timeouts
    if (response.status === 504) {
      return Promise.reject({
        error: {
          message: 'Request timed out'
        }
      })
    }
    return response.json()
  }).then(responseJson => {
    // https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1816
    // https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1913
    if (responseJson.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(responseJson.errors[0])
    }
    return Promise.resolve(responseJson)
  })
}
```